# Options Dropdown (select > option) in Internet explorer is overlapping using angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have an AngularJS application that is also using bootstrap. This query is particularly regarding the issue I am facing in select options in Internet explorer where the options drop down is overlapping the select component.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should show some code and maybe a picture of this specific problem, so we can help you

Comment: I believe it is related to the issue in the following link :- 

Link - https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-41235

Even I am struggling with the same. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks